# Efficient way to both predict and evaluate with a keras model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am writing a custom training loop for GANs and at some point I want to both evaluate my model metrics and use its output (images), in this case to draw the images in tensorboard.

I wanted to know if there was a way to efficiently do `evaluate_generator` and `predict_generator` at the same time.

I saw this [Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6790), but it has been marked as stale without intervention from keras developpers. Since not a lot of people seem to have this issue, I guess there is a way to do it efficiently, but I haven't figured out how.

Comment: Have you tried to write your own callbacks?

Comment: what do you mean by that? I am indeed writing a custom callback and that's why I need to know if there exists a way to efficiently predict and evaluate.